# Do the bonus levels have infinite waves or is there a large reward at the end?

Tags: lotr-war-in-the-north

I have played through two of these extra levels, but left them until I started playing on Hero difficulty. Because of this, it is quite hard to survive for too many rounds. So I wanted to ask, do these bonus levels have infinite waves or not? And, before I take the time to try to beat these levels, is there a big pay out at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completed both bonus levels; they only have about 20 waves each. There's also no special reward, aside from some experience points.

Answer (score 3):

I played the challenge missions on normal, heroic and legandary difficulty. 
Lorien is easier en stops at level 16, Osgiliath is harder and stops at level 20/21. 
Level 5, 12 and 20 (or 21) are boss levels. For example level 5: 1 troll, level 21: 2 or 3 armored trolls.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't make it so far in Osgiliath, however I almost got near to the end in Lorien. Aside from experience points, I also managed to work out some tactical maneuvers that I couldn't when actually on missions. Other than that, no loot to speak of, and I think I'll only go back when I wish to grind out some leveling.

Answer (score 0):

The number of waves must depend of difficulty level. In **normal**, I had to beat **16 waves** in both locations.

If you want to retain the **XP points gained** (the only reward) you must exit the location without dying (either winning the challenge or escaping it). However, the items you spend and the damage your equipment took will retain too.